# How to set Grandtotal / BaseGrandTotal with Observer?

Tags: php, magento, discount, vcs-checkout

**Config.xml**

```
        <sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
            <observers>
                <discount>
                    <class>discount/observer</class>
                    <method>discountMethod</method>
                </discount>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
```

---

**Observer.php**

```
public function discountMethod($observer)
{
   $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
   $quote->setGrandTotal(1);
   $quote->setBaseGrandTotal(1);
   $quote->save();
}
```

---

I've already created the config.xml and Observer.php and that code doesn't work at all. $quote->getData() shows:

```
[grand_total] => 1
[base_grand_total] => 1
```

But the GrandTotal on page still show the true price
[image: GrandTotal]

I'm using **Default Magento 1.6.2** and on **checkout/onepage/index** the function is triggered every I clicked **continue** but I don't know how to set the grandTotal / BaseGrandTotal on quote.

Answer (score 4):

you are listening to `sales_quote_collect_totals_before` so the totals including the `grandTotal` are collected after this event and the total collector will reset `grandTotal` to 0 when it runs.

if you are using `sales_quote_collect_totals_after` instead the total should be correct but the tax calculation will be messed up, because it will be based on the old totals.

the only clean way i can think of is creating your own total collector with `<before>tax</before>`

here is a link on how to create a new total collector:
http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-discount-total-magento

hope that helps